# Are PL-homeomorphic manifolds diffeomorphic?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, triangulation

Take two smooth manifolds. Since they are smooth, they both possess triangulations. Now assume that the triangulations are related by [Pachner moves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pachner_moves), that is, the triangulated manifolds are PL-homeomorphic. Are the manifolds smooth then?

I guess I'm asking whether the inclusion of smooth manifolds into PL-manifolds is full.

Comment: The categories of PL and smooth manifolds are equivalent in dimensions $n \leq 6$, but not above that, as Dario points out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for example one of [Milnor's exotic $7-$spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) and the standard $7-$sphere: they are PL-homeomorphic since the [generalized Poincaré conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture) in the PL category is true in dimensions different than 4 (i.e. any two PL-manifold which is a homotopy sphere is PL-homeomorphic to a sphere), but they are not diffeomorphic as shown by Milnor.

Moreover there are PL manifolds which do not admit a compatible differentiable structure (e.g. Kervaire provided such an example).

References:

- M. Kervaire, A manifold which does not admit any differentiable structure, Comm. Math. Helv. 34 (1960), 257–270.
- J. W. Milnor, "On manifolds homeomorphic to the 7-sphere", Annals of Mathematics 64 (2) (1956), 399–405