# Topological spaces that are homeomorphic but not PL-homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to understand basic concepts in piecewise-linear topology. It seems the most basic concept is "piecewise-linear homeomorphism". What are simple examples of <s>topological spaces</s> manifolds, that are homeomorphic but not PL-homeomorphic?

[The nearest answer I found was [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1236449/): the Milnor sphere and the standard sphere are homeomorphic, and PL-homeomorphic, but they are not diffeomorphic.]

Comment: You should rewrite your question, for instance, replace "topological spaces" by "PL manifolds" and remove the word "simple" since it is subjective. Or maybe you do not want to restrict to manifolds and you mean "simplicial complexes"? Then read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will ignore the request for a "simple" example: As far as I know, all the known examples require quite a bit of hard work.

Theorem. For every $n\ge 5$ there exists a triangulated manifold $(M,\tau)$ homeomorphic to the standard $n$-dimensional torus $T^n$ but not PL homeomorphic to it.

Proof. The reference is essentially page 3 of "The Hauptvermutung book." By reading page 3,  you see that there exists $(M,\tau)$ and a homeomorphism
$$
f: (M,\tau)\to T^n
$$
not homotopic to a PL homeomorphism. (The proof is quite hard.) Suppose that
$$
g: (M,\tau)\to T^n
$$
is another homeomorphism. Then the composition $f\circ g^{-1}: T^n\to T^n$ is a self-homeomorphism. Each self-homotopy-equivalence of $T^n$ is homotopic to an affine map $A: T^n\to T^n$ (i.e. a map which lifts to an affine self-map the universal covering space of the standard torus, which is the Euclidean space $E^n$): This is a nice exercise in application of Whitehead'd theorem on CW complexes with contractible universal covers. An affine self-map of the torus is PL, of course. Thus, if $g$ were to be a PL homeomorphism $(M,\tau)\to T^n$, then $f$ would be homotopic to the PL homeomorphism $A\circ g$, which is a contradiction. Thus, there are no PL homeomorphisms $(M,\tau)\to T^n$.

Comment: Thanks! The second part of the proof was the missing link.

Answer (score 1):

There are PL-manifolds which are homeomorphic but not PL-homeomorphic. This is a highly non-trivial result.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hauptvermutung). A more detailed exposition can be found in

> [Ranicki, A. A., et al. "The hauptvermutung book." Collection of papers by Casson, Sullivan, Armstrong, Cooke, Rourke and Ranicki, K-Monographs in Mathematics 1 (1996).](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/books/haupt.pdf)

In

> Kirby, R. C., & Siebenmann, L. C. (1969). On the triangulation of manifolds and the Hauptvermutung. Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, 75(4), 742-749

you can explicitly find the following theorem:

- Given one PL structure on $M$, the isotopy classes of PL
  structures on $M$ are in (1-1)-correspondence with the elements of
  $H^3(M; \pi_3(TOP/PL))$.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. In the book, the conjecture is stated as "Every homeomorphism f : |K|−→|L| of the polyhedra of compact m-dimensional PL manifolds is homotopic to a PL homeomorphism." This conjecture is false, but it only implies that not *every* homeomorphism is homotopic to a PL homeomorphism; but it does not rule out the possibility that *some* homeomorphism is homotopic to a PL homeomorphism.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi See my update.