# A combinatorial definition of a piecewise-linear sphere

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, spheres, simplicial-complex

Define a **piecewise-linear sphere (PL sphere)** as an abstract simplicial complex, whose gemoetric realization is homeomorphic to a sphere. Examples:

- The complex over {1,2,3} which contains the sets {1,2},{2,3},{3,1} and their subsets is a PL sphere, since its geometric realization is the perimeter of a triangle, which is homeomorphic to a circle (a 1-dimensional sphere).
- The complex that contains, in addition, the set {1,2,3} is not a PL sphere, since its geometric realization is a full triangle, which is homeomorphic to a disk (a 2-dimensional ball) and not to a sphere,

Is there a combinatorial definition of a PL sphere, that considers only the elements in the abstract simplicial complex, and does not require to go through the geometric realization?

One idea that I had, based on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(topology)#Piecewise_linear_structures), is to use a recursive definition:

- A PL 0-sphere is a complex containing two disjoint points, e.g.{{x},{y}} for some points x,y.
- A PL $(n+1)$-sphere is a complex in which the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_(simplicial_complex)) of every vertex is a PL $n$-sphere.

For example, in the complex {{1,2},{2,3},{3,1}}, the link of 1 is {{2},{3}}, which is a 0-sphere; similarly, the link of 2 is {{1},{3}} and the link of 3 is {{1},{2}}, which are 0-spheres too.

However, by this definition, the complex over containing the sets {1,2},{2,3},{3,1},{4,5},{5,6},{6,4} would also be considered a PL 1-sphere, although it is in fact homeomorphic to two disjoint circles.

Is it possible to amend my definition and provide a correct combinatorial definition of a PL sphere?

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of a "combinatorial definition"? It's not a standard terminology, so if you have something specific in mind it would be good to know. Part of the reason I ask is this. Suppose one alters the wording or your question to obtain the following: "Is there an algorithm to determine whether the geometric realization of an abstract, finite simplicial complex is homeomorphic to a sphere?" Well, attempts to resolve that problem have led to some of the deepest results of 20th century topology.

Comment: Perhaps it is already worthwhile pointing out that *some* of the difficulties in answering this question should already be evident from the answers to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4575140/topological-spaces-that-are-homeomorphic-but-not-pl-homeomorphic).

Comment: @LeeMosher By "combinatorial definition" I mean a definition that only considers the abstract simplicial complex as a finite set of finite sets, and does not translate it to uncountable objects such as a geometric sphere. Actually, I wanted to ask about an algorithm, but then I found out that there is provably no algorithm for detecting a sphere of dimension 5 or more, so I lowered my expectations...

Comment: Well I still wonder: an abstract simplicial complex is a finitistic object. If your concept of combinatorial definition is supposed to not involve uncountable objects, it *sounds like* you are asking for a definition which is algorithmic, i.e. a definition which in and of itself is an algorithm for verifying the definition. But your last comment also makes clear that this is not your intention, so I am left in the dark regarding a "combinatorial definition".

Comment: I don't know if I have much more to add, *but* let me say that the historical intention of the definition of a PL manifold was for applications to topology. The problems solved by 20th century PL topology were all topology problems, e.g. "Is every PL structure on the $n$-sphere PL equivalent to the standard PL structure?"

Comment: For that purpose there is a "combinatorial" definition of a PL manifold. But begging for a combinatorial definition of a PL sphere is attempting to make an end run around all of those hard topological theorems. For that reason, I would say that a "combinatorial definition" of a PL sphere, in the strong sense that you ask for, does not exist.

Comment: Actually, I have to take back part of my last comment. The definition of a PL manifold is not actually combinatorial in the sense that you ask for. The definition of a PL $n$-manifold is an inductive definition, requiring you to already know the definition of a PL $k$-sphere for $k =n-1$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I found a combinatorial property that is not algorithmic. In [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11856-015-1206-4) it is proved that every PL sphere becomes polytopal after finitely many derived subdivisions; polytopality can be decided by a finite algorithm. It does not contradict the undecidability of detecting a PL sphere, since there is no algorithm that can compute *how many* derived subdivisions are needed to convert a given PL sphere to a polytope.

Comment: Ooh! Very interesting, thanks!

Comment: By the way, perhaps this is a good fit for answering your own question.

Comment: Your initial definition of a PL sphere is wrong already in dimension 5.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I searched but did not find a formal definition of a PL sphere. Can you refer me to one?

Comment: Do you know what a PL manifold is? What a PL homeomorphism is? If you do, then it is a PL manifold PL homeomirphic to the boundary of the $n+1$-dimensional simplex.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I was hoping for an algorithmic definition. Unfortunately, such a definition does not exist in general, since the problem of recognizing a sphere of dimension 5 and higher is undecidable (see the [simplicial complex recognition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex_recognition_problem))

But, I found a combinatorial definition that is not algorithmic. In [this paper (Karim A. Adiprasito and Ivan Izmestiev, 2015)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11856-015-1206-4) it is proved that every PL sphere becomes polytopal after finitely many derived subdivisions. The converse is obviously true too. So a definition could be: "$C$ is a PL-sphere if and only if there exists a finite integer $k$ such that, after some $k$ derived subdivisions, $C$ becomes polytopal".

Note that polytopality can be decided by a finite algorithm. It does not contradict the undecidability of detecting a PL sphere, since there is no algorithm that can compute *how many* derived subdivisions are needed to convert a given PL sphere to a polytope.